# How set display format and similar properties of QDateTimeEdit in a QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I set the - say - [displayFormat](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qdatetimeedit.html#displayFormat-prop) and the [calendarPopup](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qdatetimeedit.html#calendarPopup-prop) property of QDateTimeEdit objects that are used in a QTreeView?

(They are used when editing a `QVariant(QDateTime)` value there.)

Is it possible to use [Qt's property system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/properties.html) for that purpose?

Unfortunately, the [Style Sheets Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/stylesheet-reference.html#qdatetimeedit-widget) does not list those properties for QDateTimeEdit. On the other hand, the [documentation mentions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/stylesheet-syntax.html#setting-qobject-properties) that:

> From 4.3 and above, any designable Q_PROPERTY can be set using the qproperty- syntax.

Thus, I've tried something like this:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
// first try
// app.setStyleSheet(
//  " QDateTimeEdit { displayFormat: \"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss\" ; }");
app.setStyleSheet(
  " QDateTimeEdit { qproperty-displayFormat: \"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss\" ; }");
```

Both style-sheets are not picked up, though.

What is the correct stylesheet syntax for setting those properties?

Or is there another way to set default values for those properties in an application?

Comment: Do you use a model for your tree view?

Comment: @vahancho, yes, a `QAbstractItemModel`. And the model's `data()` member returns for some indexes a `QVariant(QDateTime)` value.

Comment: What prevents you from returning formatted date/time values from the data() function?

Comment: @vahancho, the fact that then the `QTreeView` will use a `QEditLine` on them and not a `QDateTimeEdit` widget. And `QDateTimeEdit` is superior for such values because it makes changing dates/times more convenient and even provides a calendar popup ...

Comment: You could try to use the item delegate for your tree view nodes editing (QDateTimeEdit) and return formatted strings from data() function.

Answer (score 1):

The QDateTime display format used in a TableView, TreeView or ListView can be modified by modifying the ItemDelegate.

In this method, we derive StyledItemDelegate to override createEditor and displayText methods and then apply the new delegate to the desired view.

DateFormatDelegate.hpp :

```
#include <qstyleditemdelegate.h>

class DateFormatDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
  explicit DateFormatDelegate(QObject* parent = Q_NULLPTR)
     :QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}
  QString displayText(const QVariant& value, const QLocale& locale) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
  QWidget * createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
};
```

DateFormatDelegate.cpp :

```
QString DateFormatDelegate::displayText(const QVariant& value, const QLocale& locale) const
{
  switch (value.type()) {
    case QVariant::DateTime:
      return locale.toString(value.toDateTime(), "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
    default:
      return QStyledItemDelegate::displayText(value, locale);
  }
}

QWidget *DateFormatDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
  QWidget* widget = QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option,index);
  if( strcmp(widget->metaObject()->className(),"QDateTimeEdit") == 0)
      dynamic_cast<QDateTimeEdit*>(widget)->setDisplayFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
  return widget;
}
```

You can then set the new delegate to your view :

```
ui->TableView_MyTable->setIteemDelegate(
      new DateFormatDelegate(ui->TableView_MyTable)));
```

it can also be applied directly in the constructor if you have derived the view.

This method allows to modify any editor widget's style without worrying of later modification or your view organization.

There might be more elegant solutions though.